# How to pass a variable between to steps in DataProc's workflow?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dataproc

I need to get the result of calculation as variable of previous step in DataProc workflow. (Something like xcom_pull in Airflow).

For example:
My Cloud Function initiates a workflow which contains several consecutive steps.

First step receives a link of the file and makes calculations and returns as result.
Second step has to get this value. But i don't know how to do this.

How it can get it? Is it possible?

I've tried to search info in documentation. But i did't find anything helpful.